# MouseWheel event not registering minor movements

Tags: c#, mousewheel

I thought I would improve my program by adding granular scrolling, hence I am studying up on the mouse wheel delta.

I have a new Logitech mouse with smooth scrolling enabled. Testing the scrolling on Chrome and I barely have to touch the scroll wheel and the page scrolls up one pixel. Nice!

I have a test program in c# with the MouseWheel event connected to a form with a few labels. Nothing fancy:

```
private void MainForm_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    int lines =  e.Delta / 120;

    if (lines > MaxLines)
        MaxLines = lines;
    else if (lines < MinLines)
        MinLines = lines;

    deltaResult.Text = e.Delta.ToString();
    linesResult.Text = lines.ToString();
    minLinesResult.Text = MinLines.ToString();
    maxLinesResult.Text = MaxLines.ToString();
}
```

Trouble is this event only gets called when the delta reaches 120 (+/-). I understand that the mouse should be firing more events with lower value deltas, which it apparently works for Chrome, but for the test code, I have to move the scroll wheel considerably further before the event is fired.

I have come to the conclusion that either granular scrolling is not possible in C#; or that there is another event I should be calling; or it is something that needs to be enabled within the program; or that there is another method somewhere adding up the Deltas until they reach 120 and then firing the MouseWheel event.

**My specific question:**

*How do I get the MouseWheel event to fire with only a minute rotation of the mouse wheel such as Chrome is obviously doing? If this is not possible, what event should I be calling?*

Comment: hi, interesting, the delta is not necessarily a multiple of 120, so you may need to accumulate the delta yourself until it reaches the threshold you're targeting.

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that the event is only firing when the delta is already at 120. I have to move the mouse wheel a fair bit before the event is fired, whereas Google Chrome moves with just the smallest of movement.

Comment: @damichab did you find an answer to this problem? I am facing the same issue. Wondering why the Logitech mouse only sends 120 or -120.